# Copy with symblic link

Tags: hyperlink, copy, cp

I have a directory which has many libraries (ex. A,B,C) and few with symbolic link to the libraries in the same directory (ex. A1, A2 and A3 are symbolic link to A). I am copying this directory from from orignal location to another location preserving the symbolic link information of these libraries.

So my command is something like this
cp -Rp

This works well in shell.

If i move this command to makefile, the -p option can't work the way it works from shell. In makefile, the symbolic links are not maintained and instead all the libraries are just copied.
Do you have a solution which retains sym link on copying from makefile.mk

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To preserve symbolic links, I think you need `-d` / `--no-dereference`, or `--preserve=links`

Or maybe just `-a` (= `-dR` )

> `cp -a`